# 0 not a valid FILE* when provided as a template argument

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
template <typename T, T v> class Tem
{
    T t;
    Tem()
    {
        t = v;
    }
};

typedef Tem<FILE*,NULL> TemFile;
```

when compiled in a .mm file (Objective C++) by Xcode on MacOS X, throws the following error:

error: could not convert template argument '0' to 'FILE*'.

What's going on, please? The code in question compiled fine under MSVC. Since when is the 0 constant not a valid pointer to anything? Is this an artifact of Objective C++ (as opposed to vanilla C++)?

Comment: For what it's worth, use the initialization list to initialize members: `Tem() : t(v) {}`

Comment: Hmm, code looks like "vanilla" C++. I thought objective C++ looks like "[stuff here] scary-tokens there". Or was that objective-C oO

Comment: Can't believe it's a Microsoft's proprietary extension. Are integer template parameters prohibited, too?

Comment: @Johannes: Haha, yea that's Objective-C. @Seva: Well, it is. :|

Comment: How are you supposed to implement a safe-handle class, then?

Comment: @Seva: Do this in the constructor to get a default-initialized values. (0 for pointers): `Tem() : t() {}`

Comment: Not all handles are pointers, or have a default/none value of 0. File descriptors, for example...

Comment: @Seva: non-pointer, non-integral handles can't be template arguments. Integral handles such as FD's can be template-initialized to anything. Here, you're already introducing pointers to work around the non-pointer/non-integral case.

Comment: Apparently so, they can't. And that's the sad part. Under MSVC, they can. And I here thought that Microsoft's implementation of templates was behind the pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard, you are out of luck. There is no way to initialize a pointer argument to anything besides the address-of a global. §14.3.2/1:

> A template-argument for a non-type,
>   non-template template-parameter shall
>   be one of:
>
> - an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - the address of an object or function with external linkage, including
>     function templates and function
>     template-ids but excluding non-static
>     class members, **expressed as &
>     id-expression where the & is optional**
>     if the name refers to a function or
>     array, or if the corresponding
>     template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1 .

§14.3.2/5:

> - for a non-type template-parameter of
>     type pointer to object, qualification
>     conversions (4.4) and the
>     array-to-pointer conversion (4.2) are
>     applied. [Note: In particular, neither
>     the null pointer conversion (4.10) nor
>     the derived-to-base conversion (4.10)
>     are applied. Although 0 is a valid
>     template-argument for a non-type
>     template-parameter of integral type,
>     it is not a valid template-argument
>     for a non-type template-parameter of
>     pointer type. ]

However, Comeau accepts this invalid workaround:

```
typedef Tem<FILE*, (FILE *) NULL > TemFile;
```

And this code has a slim chance of compliance: I can't find where the standard specifically says that a default expression is used verbatim in place of a a missing argument, and I can't find a matching known defect. Anyone have a reference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
template <typename T, T *v = (T*) 0> class Tem
{
    T t;
    Tem()
    {
        t = v;
    }
};

typedef Tem<FILE> TemFile;
```

For more portability, you might consider creating a bogus `FILE FILE_NULL;`, pass `&FILE_NULL`, and test for pointer-equality with that instead of zero.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks, I missed the new bullet point they put that in and Comeau accepted it despite "turning off" C++0x.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like this?

```
typedef Tem<FILE*,((FILE*)NULL)> TemFile;
```

Perhaps it's trying to figure out the type of NULL.

Comment: That would throw a different error:

a cast to a type other than an integral or an enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression